# How can i auto-align the input boxes in my dash application?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, plotly-dash

Current Output/layout

[image]

I am new to using python for presenting my machine learning results. I am trying to run a prediction engine which receives user's inputs and provides them prediction by running the model at the back-end.

Therefore, for that i need to create a UI using plotly-dash. I have created the UI and it is working fine but all the input boxes are aligned in one column where as i want to align them in multiple columns.

I have tried changing alignment under "style" but its a very manual task

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [

        html.H1('AI for MI',style={'textAlign': 'center', 'color': 'Red'}),
        html.H1('Prediction Engine',style={'textAlign': 'center', 'color': 'Red'}),
        html.Div([html.P('Days To Maturity', style={"height": "auto","margin-bottom": "auto"}),dcc.Input(id="DaysToMaturity", type="number", value= '806.0',),]),
        html.Div([html.P('Days From Offer', style={"height": "auto","margin-bottom": "auto"}),dcc.Input(id="DaysFromOffer", type="number", value= '2879.0',),]),
        html.Div([html.P('Price', style={"height": "auto","margin-bottom": "auto"}),dcc.Input(id="Price", type="number", value= '105.033',),]),
        html.Div([html.P('Yield To Worst', style={"height": "auto","margin-bottom": "auto"}),dcc.Input(id="Yild2Worst", type="number", value= '3.414',),]),
        html.Div([html.P('Coupon Rate', style={"height": "auto","margin-bottom": "auto"}),dcc.Input(id="CouponRate", type="number", value= '5.8',),]),
        html.Div([html.P('Offering Amount', style={"height": "auto","margin-bottom": "auto"}),dcc.Input(id="OfferinAmnt", type="number", value= '450.0',),]),
        html.Div([html.P('Amount Outstanding', style={"height": "auto","margin-bottom": "auto"}),dcc.Input(id="AmntOut", type="number", value= '450.0',),]),
        html.Div([html.P('Offering Price', style={"height": "auto","margin-bottom": "auto"}),dcc.Input(id="OffPrice", type="number", value= '99.8',),]),
        html.Div([html.P('Offering Yield', style={"height": "auto","margin-bottom": "auto"}),dcc.Input(id="OffYild", type="number", value= '5.832',),]),
        html.Div([html.P('Principal Amount', style={"height": "auto","margin-bottom": "auto"}),dcc.Input(id="PrincAmnt", type="number", value= '1000.0',),]),
        html.Div([html.P('Duration', style={"height": "auto","margin-bottom": "auto"}),dcc.Input(id="Duration", type="number", value= '2.078',),]),
        html.Div([html.P('Convexity', style={"height": "auto","margin-bottom": "auto"}),dcc.Input(id="Convexity", type="number", value= '0.03',),]),
        html.Div([html.Button('Submit',style={"height": "auto","margin-bottom": "auto"}, id='button'),]),
        #html.Button('Submit', id='button'),
        html.Div(id="prediction-out", style={'color': 'black', 'font-style': 'italic', 'font-weight': 'bold'}),
    ]
)
```

Can you suggest how i can auto-align the input boxes or a way to align them in multiple columns?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```py
app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.H1('AI for MI', style={'textAlign': 'center', 'color': 'Red'}),
        html.H1('Prediction Engine', style={'textAlign': 'center', 'color': 'Red'}),
        html.Div([
            html.Div([html.P('Days To Maturity', style={"height": "auto", "margin-bottom": "auto"}),
                      dcc.Input(id="DaysToMaturity", type="number", value='806.0', ), ]),
            html.Div([html.P('Days From Offer', style={"height": "auto", "margin-bottom": "auto"}),
                      dcc.Input(id="DaysFromOffer", type="number", value='2879.0', ), ]),
            html.Div([html.P('Price', style={"height": "auto", "margin-bottom": "auto"}),
                      dcc.Input(id="Price", type="number", value='105.033', ), ]),
            html.Div([html.P('Yield To Worst', style={"height": "auto", "margin-bottom": "auto"}),
                      dcc.Input(id="Yild2Worst", type="number", value='3.414', ), ]),
            html.Div([html.P('Coupon Rate', style={"height": "auto", "margin-bottom": "auto"}),
                      dcc.Input(id="CouponRate", type="number", value='5.8', ), ]),
            html.Div([html.P('Offering Amount', style={"height": "auto", "margin-bottom": "auto"}),
                      dcc.Input(id="OfferinAmnt", type="number", value='450.0', ), ]),
            html.Div([html.P('Amount Outstanding', style={"height": "auto", "margin-bottom": "auto"}),
                      dcc.Input(id="AmntOut", type="number", value='450.0', ), ]),
            html.Div([html.P('Offering Price', style={"height": "auto", "margin-bottom": "auto"}),
                      dcc.Input(id="OffPrice", type="number", value='99.8', ), ]),
            html.Div([html.P('Offering Yield', style={"height": "auto", "margin-bottom": "auto"}),
                      dcc.Input(id="OffYild", type="number", value='5.832', ), ]),
            html.Div([html.P('Principal Amount', style={"height": "auto", "margin-bottom": "auto"}),
                      dcc.Input(id="PrincAmnt", type="number", value='1000.0', ), ]),
            html.Div([html.P('Duration', style={"height": "auto", "margin-bottom": "auto"}),
                      dcc.Input(id="Duration", type="number", value='2.078', ), ]),
            html.Div([html.P('Convexity', style={"height": "auto", "margin-bottom": "auto"}),
                      dcc.Input(id="Convexity", type="number", value='0.03', ), ]),
        ], style=dict(display='flex', flexWrap='wrap', width=400)),
        html.Div([html.Button('Submit', style={"height": "auto", "margin-bottom": "auto"},
                              id='button'), ]),
        # html.Button('Submit', id='button'),
        html.Div(id="prediction-out",
                 style={'color': 'black', 'font-style': 'italic', 'font-weight': 'bold'}),
    ]
)
```

And that will give you something that looks like this:

[image]

After that, just adjust the width you want for the containing `div`, and the boxes will reorganize automatically within it.